# distinct on single column along with fetching corresponding data from other columns in Hive

Tags: hive

My problem is if I have a table in hive which is like

source - destination

1  ----------    2

1    ---------      3

2      --------- 1

3        ----------1

2          ----------2

1       ----------3

Now I need to get distinct source values for every destination, so output would be like

destination        source

1     --------------        2 3

2     --------------           1 2

3     --------------           1

where sources are separated by ctrl+A ('\0001')

I have tried many things but I dint get solution to this problem.
Can we have some hive script which could solve this problem?

Thanks & Regards,
Sreelatha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **collect_set** should work here. Try running this query:

```
select destination, collect_set(source) from table GROUP BY destination
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Amar, But is there any way that we could replace commas in output such that we can get output in specific delimited format? like <destination> ^A<source >^A<source Doc2>^A … and save this output to a file.

Comment: cast the output of collect_set as a string and do a regexp_replace to get your desired delimiter